# Is there any other way of setting line values in Suitescript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have made JSON data from the lines of a custom record and then I am setting its values in the lines of another rec(opportunity) after loading it.
I have heard by my senior that it's not correct to load record in loops. So, is there any other more efficient way of doing it?

My Suitelet script Code is as follows:

the JSON DATA: `[ { "item": "35", "contractPrice": "321.00" }, { "item": "36", "contractPrice": "123.00" } ]`

```
    for (var ii = 0; ii < itemArray.length; ii++) {
      var oppRec = record.load({ type: 'opportunity', id: oppRef });
      var qtyValue = oppRec.getSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'quantity',
        line: ii
      });
      log.debug('qtyValue: ' + ii, qtyValue)

      oppRec.setSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'rate',
        line: ii,
        value: itemArray[ii].contractPrice
      });

      oppRec.setSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'custcol_rate_updated',
        line: ii,
        value: true
      });

      oppRec.save({ enableSourcing: true, ignoreMandatoryFields: true });
      log.debug('COMPLETED', 'Opportunity line('+ii+') updated!')
    }
```

Comment: Your question could be better on Code Review site of SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks pretty standard from my experience.  Actually, your code is much cleaner than the code that I normally encounter (usually written by consulting firms).  I would suggest asking your associate to teach you what they mean, instead of just saying that you are doing it wrong.  ;)

The only issue I see is that you would want to move the load and save to outside of the loop.  Right now you will be loading and saving the record on every iteration.  Which is normally not needed or wanted (uses a lot more governance).

Comment: :D Thanks w3bguy !
Yes i will surely take save rec out. thanks alot

Comment: I would suggest joining the NetSuite professionals slack, as well.  Tons of super smart people there.  netsuiteprofessionals.slack.com

Comment: i will surely join that. thanks a ton